# UBUNTU 22.04 LTS - Changing brightness with xrandr doesn't work

Tags: command-line, brightness, 22.04, xrandr, wayland

In the CLI, `xrandr --output MONITOR_NAME --brightness 0.7` seemingly "works" because no feedback is shown.

After using `xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness`, `Brightness: 0.70` is shown as output but no visual changes occured.

I rebooted the system to check if this was needed but no.
An other `xrandr --verbose | grep Brightness` later, `Brightness: 0.0` is shown.

Could this be related to my monitor being 'WAYLAND0'?
If so, is there a way to change that?
I run a Linux Mate 20 on the side, and my very same monitor is displayed as 'VGA-1' there, and xrandr works fine.

Thank you!

Edit: I went to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and removed the `#` from `#WaylandEnable=false`, which gave me back the 'VGA-1' output after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here after having the same problem, I had created a script using xrandr to control brightness that no longer works with Wayland.

**This is not a complete answer**, although what I've found so far might help you.

The alternative to `xrandr` in Wayland is `wlr-randr`, which for some reason is not working for me in Ubuntu 22.04 due to the following error:

```
compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1
```

Another alternative written in rust, does have the brightness functionality implemented but only in a test branch, [see this issue](https://github.com/maxwellainatchi/gnome-randr-rust/issues/16).

You might find yourself looking for other functionalities or tools in Wayland, so I'll leave [this other link](https://arewewaylandyet.com/) if needed.

I'll edit this answer if I get this working somehow.

Answer (score 0):

xrandr failed to set the brightness for my external display too. I found a workaround in another Ask Ubuntu post and it worked for me. It uses the Soft Brightness GNOME extension. See it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403810/1647384