# adjust external monitor brightness from command line [ubuntu 22.04 wayland] (xrandr not working)

Tags: command-line, 22.04, brightness, xrandr, wayland

I'm in the process of moving from a machine running 20.04 (windowing system X11) to a new one running 22.04 (windowing system Wayland), and I have not been able to find a functional method for adjusting monitor brightness from the command line.

I have tried the following on the new machine:

- Running `xrandr --output MONITOR_NAME --brightness 0.5`  (on my new machine `MONITOR_NAME` is `XWAYLAND0` or similar, while on the old it was `HDMI-1`): the command appears to run without error, but the brightness does not change.
- Changing the windowing system from Wayland back to X11 (as suggested by [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412521/ubuntu-22-04-lts-changing-brightness-with-xrandr-doesnt-work)): this seemed to cause unrecoverable screen freezes, and I had to force several reboots before I was able to put it back to Wayland.
- Using `wlr-randr`: I get an error that says `compositor doesn't support wlr-output-management-unstable-v1`, and further investigation indeed suggests [gnome doesn't support wlr-randr](https://todo.sr.ht/%7Eemersion/wlr-randr/9)

Has anyone come up with a functional method for changing brightness from the command line in 22.04 with Wayland as the windowing system?

(My end goal here is to be able to run an alias `dim` in the terminal and have it dim my external monitor to a pre-selected level, which worked very nicely on my old laptop but doesn't seem possible now.)

Edit:
The solutions suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286458/does-wayland-have-an-equivalent-of-xrandr-for-changing-brightness-and-color-temp) also don't seem to work so far, since I'm specifically hoping to adjust brightness on an external monitor.

- `gammastep` throws the error `Error: Failed to start adjustment method: wayland` (and doesn't seem like an optimized tool for brightness-specific changes in the first place)
- As noted in the other question, `brightnessctl` and `light` don't recognize external monitors - it looks like there might be an option to fiddle around with a kernel module and get `brightnessctl` to work, so I'm going to try that next, but I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't require that.
- As noted above, `wlr-randr` isn't supported by gnome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Wayland have an equivalent of xrandr for changing brightness and color temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286458/does-wayland-have-an-equivalent-of-xrandr-for-changing-brightness-and-color-temp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already found something that works for you, but what I found and worked for me was the ddcutil cli to directly send the commands to the monitor:
https://moverest.xyz/blog/control-display-with-ddc-ci/